# Драйвер для подключения к БД

Tags: база-данных, java

Здравствуйте! У меня есть апплет, написанный на Java. Этот апплет использует драйвер, берет из директории JRE (папка, где находится виртуальная машина Java на локальном компьютере). 
Но если драйвер в эту папку не поместить, то не соединишься(. 
Мне кажется, что пользователям будет неудобно самим скачивать и перемещать этот драйвер в JRE.

Как можно "включить" драйвер в апплет, или разместить драйвер на сервере? В общем, помогите))

P.S. Сам апплет лежит на сервере и БД тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Драйвер должен находиться в `CLASSPATH` - поместите JAR с драйвером в `CLASSPATH` и все будет пучком.

CLASSPATH апплета фактически это архив (JAR) с кодом. В теге `<applet>` есть такой атрибут `archive`

Читать [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html)